# No license for domain 'xxxx' was found

Tags: kentico

Kentico: No license for domain 'xxxx' was found 
Our Scenario is:
1- Install Kentico 9 on server X1

2- In MS visual studio Create new Ap.net Web API.
3- Host/Put this web api on server other than Kentico server like server X2 on the same network.
4- Configure this Web api to communicate and consume Kentico api.
5- In your custom web api Create a new controller action to execute  "Add to cart" Kentico E-Commerce feature.
6- Try To make a request to your custom API using the "server name or IP" Not using "localhost".
            E.g:->> http://myserverx2/api/cart/addtocart/

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is expected behaviour with Kentico if you've not created any additional licences.  Each Kentico license covers a single server only, so at best, you'd be looking to register a domain alias licence key for the alternate host.